# Android Toolbar Search hide when it is open

Tags: android, search, toolbar

I have a `ActionBar` containing a search and when I switch fragment, I want this search to disappear.
If the search has closed, just make a `setVisible (false)` that implies, however, that the search has opened can not hide using `setVisible (false)`.
Is there a way to hide the search when opened (and without closing it implicit form)?

Comment: Is your search tied to just a single fragment (i.e., it should only show when that fragment is visible and disappear when the fragment is replaced with another one)?

Comment: Yes, that's it.
But I want to keep the status of research, ie to keep the query and the filtered list in view of the query